# I can't install sublime text2

Tags: 13.04, sublime-text

I can't install sublime text2 using the command "sudo apt-get install sublime-text".
This command produse an error 
"E: Unable to locate package sublime-text".
How can I install this? plz hlp me.....

Answer (score 0):

go to sublime text website,click downloads

you have two options

sublime text 2  ,click linux 32 or 64bit link,unzip it , double click sublime_text

sublime text 3 beta ,you can get ubuntu debian package similar to windows installer, if you use this you can see sublime text in the menu.